# Calling fn.apply(bar,[]) after binding function to baz

Tags: javascript, node.js

Wondering what takes precedence in JavaScript/Node.js

if I do this:

```
var baz = {};
var bar = {};

var fn = function foo(){}.bind(baz);

fn.apply(bar, []);
```

will fn always have the context of baz? Any reason why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fn` function will always have the context set to `baz` object. It is implemented this way to be sure that after using `bind` you'll have no context loss.

From MDN [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) of `bind()` method:

> The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the
>   same function body (internal call property in ECMAScript 5 terms) as
>   the function it is being called on (the bound function's target
>   function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(),
>   which **cannot be overridden**.

---

There is one exception when bound function can receive another context: `fn` is invoked as a constructor: `var o = new fn()`. In this case the context will become the new instance object (but this should be avoided and use for constructors normal functions).

[This chapter](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/#6boundfunction) describes in details the `.bind()` method.

Comment: If it is copied from somewhere..You must provide it as [reference...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: I believe arrow functions are just implemented with bind, I guess one way to verify this without looking at the source is to see if that constructor thing you mention is true

Comment: @AlexMills For arrow functions you'll receive an error: `Uncaught TypeError: t is not a constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you test

```
var baz = {a:1},
    bar = {a:2},
     fn = function(){console.log(this.a)}.bind(baz);

fn(); // 1
fn.apply(bar); // 1 so bind takes precedence
fn.call(bar); // 1 so bind takes precedence
```

Comment: looking to find a little more info, to see if this is a hard and fast rule; for example the info about constructors overriding the bound context is something I would not have uncovered without asking

Comment: I understand your point... but still testing is good... Accordingly i am not sure if invoking `fn` as constructor changes a thing. We can test it too... `bar = {a:2}; bar = new fn(); // undefined` or like `var o = new fn(); o.a=3; fn(); // 1` so how is `fn` changing the context..?

Comment: Relying only on simple tests can be deceiving. JavaScript really isn't known for consistent implementations.